# Firebase addOnCuccessListener{} causes nullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am updating a value in the realtime database with the following code :-

```
  val databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Services")
        val service = mapOf<String, String>(
            "cost" to serviceCost,
            "name" to serviceName
        )


        databaseRef.child(name!!).updateChildren(service)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Service Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Connection Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
```

The **database is being updated exactly as I need** but the application crashes with the following error message :-

```
msg: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter it

stacktrace: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter it
at com.example.prototypeadmin.UpdateServiceActivity.onCreate$lambda-2$lambda-0(Unknown Source:7)
at com.example.prototypeadmin.UpdateServiceActivity.$r8$lambda$OCfvRKDg4t88LbX2Kozztfb3Rnw(Unknown Source:0)
at com.example.prototypeadmin.UpdateServiceActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onSuccess(Unknown Source:4)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.0:1)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7665)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:594)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Without the .addOnSuccessLister{} the app does not crash but I need to perform the Intent and Toast only on success.
I am new to Firebase realtime database. Please explain what should I do.

**Thanks in advance !** , ask for any extra information if required.

Comment: "Parameter specified as non-null is null" - have you checked each parameter to ensure that it is what you are expecting it to be? In particular `name` might need to be `service.name` and `name!!` will throw an NPE if it is actually `null`.

Comment: @samthecodingman These are not null , if any of these were null the database would not have updated , but it is being updated.

Comment: Have you tried to use `databaseRef.child(serviceName)` inseatd of `databaseRef.child(name!!)`? Does it work that way?

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I recently updated Android Studio, Kotlin, and Gradle so I'm thinking that's what is causing my issue.

Comment: I also updated the android studio recently.

Comment: @AlexMamo  I was using the just latest version of firebase BoM v29.0.2 , now I updated it to the version that was released on 16th Dec , v29.0.3 and it is not giving null pointer now . I checked again by reverting to v29.0.2 and I am getting null pointer , You are developer expert for firebase  do you think there was actually a problem in firebase older version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated firebase-analytics in my app build.gradle file and I stopped getting this error.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:20.0.2'
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why this is working?, I spent hours solving this, I was using the just latest version of  **firebase BoM** v29.0.2 , now I updated it to the version that was released on 16th Dec , v29.0.3 and it is not giving null pointer now . I checked again by reverting to v29.0.2 and I am getting null pointer .Thanks a lot!